# myetherwallet - some clarifications needed

Tags: myetherwallet

hi all

i am just starting to navigate the alt coin domain.

with regard to myetherwallet I want to see that I understand the procedure correctly so I have a few questions:

1. regarding the json file. is it really mandatory to keep it? or is it a convenience for restore purposes and better security of wallet opening? I mean, if I print the paper with the private/public key why would I need the json file? the whole paper wallet reason is to not have any digital presence as far as I understand. is it safe to say that I can simply delete the json file, not back it up and just use the printed paper wallet in the future to access my funds (using my printed private key)?

2. assume I created the wallet offline, and then transferred eth from an exchange to the newly created wallet using its public key. in order to see that the money actually got to my wallet I need to go online and check it right? i mean, how can I check the balance being offline?. but then I need to use my private key to access the wallet and this compromises my private key. what am I missing? i am confused...

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .json file contains an encrypted copy of the private key, you can keep it as a backup. But having the private key should be enough to have access to your wallet funds.

To check your balance you have to be online, but you only need your address. From MyEtherWallet "View Wallet Info" - "View balance only".

You only need your private key if you want to make a transfer. You can create the transaction online (with only your address), and sign the transaction offline, and then submit the signed transaction to an online node.